# Uncaught ReferenceError: optionsPrice is not defined

Tags: configurable-product, price, requirejs, configurable-swatches

After adding product.options.js in catalog product view i still get the error relating this. I am using configurable swatches with magic tool zoom.

Comment: M1 / M2? Which version?